# rails 4 - rake command shows deprecation warning everytime I run the rake db:migrate command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

```
[pinterestclone]$ rake db:migrate  

DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.  
Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then  
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.  
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors  
 (called from block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie> at  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.5/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:57)  

DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
 (called from block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie> at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.5/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:58)

== 20160721232702 AddUserIdToPins: migrating ==================================  
-- add_column(:pins, :user_id, :integer)  
   -> 0.0010s  
-- add_index(:pins, :user_id)  
   -> 0.0010s  
== 20160721232702 AddUserIdToPins: migrated (0.0022s) =========================
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is caused by Sprockets 3.7.0 and should be fixed in sass-rails (which uses Sprockets) shortly. See [this](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/381) for more information.

I guess Sprockets 4 requires you to register a mime type before calling register_engine.

**UPDATE**: This is now fixed in sass-rails version 5.0.6. Running `bundle update` should remove the deprecation warnings.

Comment: Is it possible that this could have messed up some of my styles? I just updated my gem library for the first time in a while and a bunch of stuff (but not everything) is being displayed incorrectly, and I'm also seeing this error. I've never really used sprockets before so its not really clear to me why this would be happening.

Comment: @thesowismine what version of sass-rails are you running?

Comment: its v 5.0.6. To be specific on what styles are being displayed incorrectly; it seems to only be effecting certain border and text colors, I'm using the foundation framework and some of its styles that I had already overwritten (but perhaps not thoroughly enough) are being displayed again. Its weird though because so far I've only noticed differences in border-color: and color:

Comment: For me worked as follows:
Add the sass rails gem to the the GemFile
a) gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.6'

Run gem install sass-rails on the terminal
a) gem install sass-rails

Run bundle install
a) bundle install --without production && bundle update

Comment: this didn't fix it for me sadly

Comment: @ctilley79 I solved it by updating the gem `less-rails` to `3.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

To fix this open your project in terminal and write  "bundle update sprockets"